# jQuery Listen for list items being added to or removed from unordered list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to listen for items being added to an unordered list, and change the class of the unordered list if the list is not empty. For example:

```
$(document).on("CHANGE IN NUMBER OF ITEMS IN UL", "#listID", function() {
    if($('#listID') > li').size() >=1) {
        $('#listID').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    else {
        $('#listID').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } 
});
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no standard event for DOM modifications.

Comment: How do items get added to the list?

Comment: @dave - items are added via a simple drag-and-drop interface.

Comment: @Barmar well, there _was_, but then it got deprecated...

Comment: @CodydeVries so handle the change in the drop event handler...

Comment: If there's no event, I could just check the number on submit button click, just figured keeping track and adding a class would be easier.

Comment: There is (or you could easily add) an event, what jQuery plugin are you using for the drag and drop?

Comment: @Alnitak - I didn't think of this - that'll do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar IMHO most of the answers on the question that you've marked as a duplicate are somewhat off the mark (including the accepted answer)

Comment: @Alnitak OK, I've reopened. There are a number of other questions about listening for DOM modifications in Javascript, but I thought one that was specific to `<ul>` would be most appropriate.

Comment: @CodydeVries I've closed the question, pointing at one which effectively asks the same without being specific to `<ul>` elements.  However what you have here is an _XY problem_ - the real answer to your problem is _not_ observing the DOM, but simply to count how many elements there are _at the point you change the list yourself_, i.e. in the "drop" event handler.

Comment: @Alnitak and Barmar thank you both for your help, between this question and the others that you've directed me to, I've got things working as they should.